# Using Bigsheets I want to refine my twitter tweets, like removing url, and # tags etc

Tags: hadoop, twitter, analytics, ibm-cloud

Is there any formula or functions which I can use to remove URL and #tags etc which come when we get the tweets using twitter in the node. I also need to make new columns which would contain the tweets which have specific keywords. But when I use the inbuilt formula "contains" in **IBM BigSheets** it is not of much help.

Finally, I need my result to extract the tweets into different columns based on the sentiment score they have got. I have attached my "twitter in" node with sentiment node to get the sentiment score. Therefore, it should make separate columns based on the score it has got and also based on the keywords it contains. Can we create a function to do so?

Comment: To answer your question, we need a bit more information. What is your setup exactly? Are you using the built-in Twitter Load functionality of dashDB? Or, are you using Insights for Twitter + dashDB + sentiments as separate nodes, say in Node-RED, and then feeding the results into BigSheets?

Comment: Thank you  for your reply. I was able to finally able to find the  solution . I was using Node-RED Twitter node to get the tweets and storing it in IBM HDFS. Which I then accessed directly from BigSheets.